# in search of a realtime php cli log system with verbosity levels

Tags: php, logging, yii2, real-time, verbosity

Im looking for a log system which works with different verbosity levels and flushes to file or console immediately. I work with yii2. They Yii2 Log is good and has info, debug, warn, error levels. But I cannot get it to work realtime to flush on screen. I have tried with `flushInterval` as 1 or even 0 but does not work. yii2 log methods have `application` param, so I can filter what parts get logged, in case some module is buggy. Many of my cli apps never die, so logs come up only after many hours like a flood.

Maybe there is a totally diff composer package which does same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are grouped on two levels:

1. Dispatcher level controlled by [`Dispatcher::$flushInterval`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-dispatcher#$flushInterval-detail).
2. Log target level controlled by [`Target::$exportInterval`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#$exportInterval-detail).

So in addition to `flushInterval`, you need to also configure [`exportInterval`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#$exportInterval-detail) for given target, if you want to export every single log one by one:

```php
'log' => [
    'flushInterval' => 1,
    'targets' => [
        'file' => [
            'class' => yii\log\FileTarget::class,
            'exportInterval' => 1,
            'levels' => ['trace', 'info'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

But you may get better performance by calling `Yii::$app->log->flush(true)` after finishing every task on long-running process. So if you're processing 1k models in console command, you run `Yii::$app->log->flush(true)` after each model - it should greatly reduce logger overhead and still be pretty close to "real-time" (as long as processing one model does not take much time).